# Are there keyboard shortcuts for duplicate current line, move line up / down in Python IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

In Sublime (Windows), we can use some shortcuts likes,

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `D`: Duplicate line

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `UP`: Move line Up

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Down`: Move line Down

I want to know in Python IDLE, are there some keyboard shortcuts for these task?

Or can I add these shortcuts by doing something?

Any help, thanks.

Comment: IDLE is a very simple program just to enable beginners who are not familiar with real editors to get started quickly. If you already use a real editor, probably stick to that (maybe investigate if it offers options for better Python integration; many modern editors do).

Comment: In `Options > Configure IDLE` you will find keybindings on the 'Keys' tab, although the keybindable actions on offer are very basic. IDLE doesn't seem to offer keybindings for the example actions you provided.

Answer (score 4):

As [Alexander Chzhen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2039471/alexander-chzhen) has pointed out, there is no such built-in feature in idle.

Nevertheless, you can take advantage of the fact that idle (and python overall) is open source, and edit source code to suit your needs. Just go to `%localappdata%/Python3x/Lib/idlelib` and start your coding! Here's an example for the duplicate line shortcut:

1. Open `config.py` with any editor and search for `keyBindings={`.
   Add `'<<duplicate-line>>': ['<Control-Shift-Key-D>'],` to the dict:

[image: Adding duplicate line to Idle 1]

2. Next go to `editor.py` and search for `text.bind("<<untabify-region>>",`. Below that line add `text.bind("<<duplicate-line>>", fregion.duplicate_line_event)`

[image: Adding duplicate line to Idle 2]

3. Final step. Open `format.py`. Search for `class FormatRegion`, then implement this method inside of it:

```
def duplicate_line_event(self, event=None):
    """
    Duplicate line.
    """
    head, tail, chars, lines = self.get_region()
    lines.pop(-1)
    lines *= 2
    lines.append('')
    self.set_region(head, tail, chars, lines)
    return "break"
```

Finally (make sure to restart idle windows that were open before adding code) :)

[image: Adding duplicate line to Idle Result]

Comment: Wow, Thanks! ^-^ That's I'm looking for. How to cancle the selected status, after duplicate line(s)?
The cursor just stay at corresponding position of new line as the duplicated line.

I tried add `Ctrl + Shift + UP: Move line Up`, but not worked out it. I'm a newbie of Python. Could you show me how to add another two key binds: `move line up` and `move line down`?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to duplicate a slice of text is to select it, copy it, and paste it one or more times wherever one wants.  Move the cursor with either key or mouse. To easily select complete lines, including carriage returns, turn on `line numbers` on the `Options` submenu.  Then click on a line number to select one line or click and drag to select multiple lines.  To move instead of duplicate, cut instead of copy.

Answer (score -1):

There are no such [IDLE hotkeys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#key-bindings)

As a workaround you may want to use some kind of `Shift+Home` / `Shift+End` for line selection and usual copy-cut-paste hotkeys after it.

Comment: This answer is unclear. The workaround doesn't work

Comment: To easily select lines, turn on Options => Show Line Numbers and click or click-drag on the sidebar.